# Shopping cart / adding multiple items to cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a cart with React js and Redux and I have one problem.

Tried many ways but I keep failing that when I add multiple items (food/drink) to the list then everything seems to be working, but then when I want for example add additional drink to the existing choice my list gets overwritten.  Here is the code I have it now:

```
const addItemToCart = item => {
   if (cartItems.length) {
     cartItems.forEach(itemToCheck => {
       if (item.name === itemToCheck.name) {
         addCountToItem({ ...itemToCheck, count: itemToCheck.count + 1 });
       } else if (item.name !== itemToCheck.name) {
         addToCart({ ...item, count: 1 });
       }
     });
   } else if (cartItems.length === 0) {
     addToCart({ ...item, count: 1 });
   }
 };
```

Idea is that I can have multiple items on the list and unlimited number of same items within the list. So basically, I should be able to have 5 pizzas of the same type, 3 beers of different type etc.

I guess like any other cart. Thanks in advance.

update:

Here the code for addCountToItem. I deleted it but it was going something in this direction

```
state.cartItems[findIndex(...)] = data.cartItem
```

Comment: Can you share code for addToCart, addCountToItem  and your cart reducer code?

Comment: Just added what I had before I deleted.. can not recall the function entirely now :/

Comment: this is not how you add item to cart with redux. yo have to create your action and reducer and then dispatch the action to the reducer

Answer (score 0):

a basic way to solve your problem  is

```
`let index=cartItem.findIndex(temp=>temp.name===item.name);
 if(index>-1){
     cartItem[index].count++;
 }
 else{
     cartItem.append({...item, count: 1 })
 }`
```

try not to mutate cartItem object

Answer (score 0):

We need too see to all the related code to successfully answer.

Here I give sample example, updatedCartItems keeps the updated cart, you can do whatever you want. In general, this type of manipulation must be in the cart reducer, but you didn't post the the reducer code.

```
const addItemToCart = item => {
  let updatedCartItems = [...cartItems];

  updatedItemIndex = updatedCartItems.findIndex(
    item => item.name === itemToCheck.name   // better to check with some kind of id if exists
  );

  if (updatedItemIndex < 0) {
    updatedCartItems.push({ ...item, count: 1 });
  } else {
    const updatedItem = {
      ...updatedCartItems[updatedItemIndex]
    };
    updatedItem.count++;
    updatedCartItems[updatedItemIndex] = updatedItem;
  }

 //updatedCartItems  => the new cart
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for shopping card, we need to have cartItems property as array in our state, and every time we click on the addToCart button, we will push that item to that array and then we render that array in the cartDropdown component or the checkout page.

since you are able to add single item to the cart, it means that you have correct set up for redux. in order to add same item to the cart more than once, we just need to write a simple utility function.

here is the utility function:

```
export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd) => {
  //find(condition) finds the first item in the array based on the condition.
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(item => item.id === cartItemToAdd.id);
  if (existingCartItem) {
    //in order for change detection to trigger we have to rerender
    //otherwise our quantity property will not be updated
    //map will return a new array 
    //we need to return new versions of our state so that our component know to re render
    //here we update the quantity property
    return cartItems.map(item =>
      item.id === cartItemToAdd.id
        ? { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
        : item
    );
  }
  //when you first time add a new item, sine exixtingCartItem will be falsy, it will pass the first if block and will come here
  //quantity property gets attached the first time around since this if block wont run when it is a new item.
 //in the beginning cartItems array is empty. every time you add a new item to this array, it will add "quantity:1" to this item object.  
  return [...cartItems, { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
};
```

here is the action to add item to the cart

```
export const CartActionTypes = {
  ADD_ITEM: "ADD_ITEM",
};

export const addItem = item => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM,
  payload: item
});
```

since you are able to add single item to the cart, it means that you have correct set up for redux. you need to dispatch this to the reducer in the component that you render addToCart button. here is the cart reducer where the case is CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM.

```
import { addItemToCart } from "./cart.utils";

case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,

        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
```